# How to recive multiply urls from telegram bot using aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

So user should enter 3 links one by one to bot

And bot should save each link to a new variable (exmp: link1,link2,link3)

Im tried using message handler with iterating,but for some reason it doesnt work

Any workaround?

```
link1 = ''
link2 = ''
link3 = ''
counter = 1

@dp.message_handler(Text(contains="https://" or "http://",))
async def url(message: types.Message):
    if link1 == '':
        counter+1
        link1 = message.text
    elif link2 == '':
        counter+1
        link2 = message.text
    elif link3 == '':
        counter+1
        link3 = message.text
```

Answer (score 1):

There's another good way of doing this if you just want to get multiple links without some specific order.

You need only one state to do this.

```
class Links(StatesGroup):
    get = State()
```

Then register handlers which start a conversation

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["links"])
async def collect_links_start(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.reply("Send me links.\nTo finish, type or click /done")
    await Links.get.set()
    # You can use your own saving logic instead, this is just an example
    await state.update_data(links=[])
```

…, append links

```
# You can set more advanced filter for links, `text_startswith` is just an example
@dp.message_handler(text_startswith=["http"], state=Links.get)
async def collect_links(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    # You can use your own saving logic instead, this is just an example
    data = await state.get_data()
    links = data["links"]
    links.append(message.text)
    await state.update_data(links=links)

    await message.reply("Got it!\nTo finish, type or click /done")

# This handler is a fallback in case user didn't provide valid link
@dp.message_handler(state=Links.get)
async def invalid_link(message: Message):
    await message.reply("This doesn't look like a valid link!\nTo finish, type or click /done")
```

… and end the conversation.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["done"], state=Links.get)
async def collect_links_finish(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    # You can use your own loading logic instead, this is just an example
    data = await state.get_data()
    links = data["links"]
    await state.finish()
    link_list = "\n".join(links)

    await message.reply(f"Links:\n{link_list}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it,

Just need to use States in aiogram.

```
class reg(StatesGroup):
    link1 = State()
    link2 = State()
    link3 = State()
    end = State()
And just set a new state every new link
```